# sql query conflict

Tags: mysql, sql

i need a query which returns group wise max(cus_amount) and then date should be picked as last date when it modified date.

```
select cus_name , sum(cus_amount),first(cus_date)
from  credit_details
group by cus_name
```

The problem is the date picks is not correct one , if i am having 5 data it picks the 1st one , the requirement is last data which i have recently updated. Please help
my table values

```
ID  cus_id  cus_date    cus_name    cus_amount  cus_details
7   1   16/04/2014  NAGARAJAN   256 aaa
8   1   11/04/2014  NAGARAJAN   25  aaa
9   1   11/04/2014  NAGARAJAN   22  aaa 
10  4   11/04/2014  SPS 55  bbb
11  102 14/04/2014  PRK 100 25
12  102 16/04/2014  PRK 100 25
```

My requirement is:

```
Nagaraj  303 16/04/2014
sps      55  11/04/2014
prk      200 16/04/2014
```

Comment: `first()` returns the FIRST encountered record, no matter what value it has.

Comment: Use `MAX(cus_date)`.  Just a suggestion, you can use `cus_id` for grouping to improve the performance in larger tables.

Comment: groupby name then fetch the sum amount + max date in particular group according to customer name.

Comment: if i have not use first() it retuns syntax errors because i have used group by function, for name sake i have used it, it does not reflect any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cus_name, 
       SUM(cus_amount) AS totalCustomerAmount, 
       MAX(STR_TO_DATE(cus_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) AS latestDate
FROM credit_details
GROUP BY cus_names;
```

for mssql try this way:

```
SELECT cus_name, 
       SUM(cus_amount) AS totalCustomerAmount, 
       MAX(CONVERT(date,cus_date,103)) AS latestDate
FROM credit_details
GROUP BY cus_names;
```

for ms access try this:

```
SELECT cus_name, 
       SUM(cus_amount) AS totalCustomerAmount, 
       MAX(CDate(cus_date)) AS latestDate
FROM credit_details
GROUP BY cus_names;
```

Comment: do you use mysql or mssql?

Comment: i am having a field called "ID" i need max(ID) , i am not dependent with date. i need only last edited date , so if  it picks max(id) value then it might be easy to pick the date

Comment: I never asked about id. So can't understand why do you talk about that field. if you use mssql - remove mysql from tags in your post and add sql-server

Comment: what is your mssql server version?

Comment: i am using hard coding for connectivity, Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports checking.connect

Public Class update_credit
    Dim con As OleDbConnection

    Dim adp, adp1 As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim cmd, cmd1 As OleDbCommand
    Dim ds, ds1 As New DataSet  ,

Comment: what? :-) I've asked what is your MS-SQL SERVER version!

Comment: my backend is ms access .

Comment: you are really interesting person... try my very last update... I am done here. :-) good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MAX() function to get the latest date in a group:

```
SELECT cus_name, SUM(cus_amount) AS totalCustomerAmount, MAX(cus_date) AS latestDate
FROM credit_details
GROUP BY cus_names;
```

Comment: Dim s As String = "select cus_name , sum(cus_amount),max(cus_date) from credit_details group by cus_name" . i have used same value returns

Comment: @User_Pree show us your code? what language do you use?

Comment: @Alex i am using vb.net   , which part you needed ? i will show it ...i am using oledb connectivity , backend access .

Comment: @User_Pree you posted your expected values, what are the values you're actually getting?

Comment: **Dim s As String = "select cus_name , sum(cus_amount),max(cus_date) from credit_details group by cus_name" ** do you have some errors there? Show us the fragment of your code where you query the database

Comment: @Alex the date field is text datatype .

Comment: why? can you change that to DATE?

Comment: That explains why this didn't work. If the field was `DATETIME` or `DATE` this would have been perfect.

Comment: @McAdam331 the value i am getting is same as required , but the date field differs  Nagaraj  303 11/04/2014
sps      55  11/04/2014
prk      200 14/04/2014

Comment: @Alex while I appreciate your help, I would post your own answer rather than edit mine, it will only cause more confusion.

Comment: @Alex i have few manipulation task in that field that's i have used it as text type , just wait i will show it off what task i have did with that field  Dim oday = DateTime.ParseExact(ds.Tables("updc").Rows(tmp_flag).Item(2).ToString, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)
                '   Date.Parse(ds.Tables("updc").Rows(tmp_flag).Item(2).ToString)
                diff = tday.Subtract(oday).TotalDays
      This is for counting no. of days different between two dates

Comment: if you have another question how to calculate difference between dates we can discuss it there. If you see a good reason to keep your table structure with string - that is up to you. my opinion - data type must match the data you store in column. so if that is date - must be date, if int - must be int, if string then varchar etc...

Comment: @alex i am agree with you , this app was developed 6 month before.